# Can't run discord bot (JavaScript)

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, node-modules, replit

I can't get the bot to run on the replit platform. I used the command **node .** and **npm start**. I am getting an error:

```
  throw new Error(`Could not find fetch library. Install "node-fetch"/"undici" or define "fetch" in global scope!`);
  ^

Error: Could not find fetch library. Install "node-fetch"/"undici" or define "fetch" in global scope!
    at getFetch (/home/runner/qwerty1/node_modules/youtube-sr/dist/mod.js:428:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/qwerty1/node_modules/youtube-sr/dist/mod.js:411:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/qwerty1/node_modules/discord-player/lib/utils/Util.js:17:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/qwerty1/node_modules/discord-player/lib/Player.js:18:32)
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I use this code: https://github.com/Tajemniq/qwerty1 as if it were needed

Comment: Please ensure you know how stack overflow tagging works, this is unrelated to discord.js or replit. Please make sure you categorise your question correctly next time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `youtube-sr` package is looking to use the `fetch` api, but there isn't a library installed to do this.

Try following the error message and install the `undici` package (which adds fetch support to node js)

```sh
npm i undici
```